# JQuery: Defining a variable is stopping my script from running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, frontend

```
<script>
    $(document).foundation(
        var count = 1
        $("button.test").click(function(){
            if ($("p.change-me").text() === "OFF") {
                $("p.change-me").text("ON")
                count = count + 1
            }
            else if ($("p.change-me").text() === "ON") {
                $("p.change-me").text("OFF")
                count = count + 1
            }
            $("p.counter").text(count)
        })
        )
</script>
```

Very simply, I want to show the count as I am pressing this On and Off button. However, when I add the "var count = 1", my button no longer works. When I get rid of that line, the button will turn the text in the tag from ON to OFF and from OFF to ON.

How come? As you can probably tell, I am teaching myself JQuery.

Thanks!

HTML as requested:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="small-6 columns text-center">
        <button class="button radius test">CLICK THIS</button>
    </div>
    <div class="small-6 columns text-center">
        <p class="change-me">OFF</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns text-center">
        <p>Here we will print how much fun you are having:</p>
        <p class="counter">0</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show us your html code too.

Comment: Why are you putting your code inside `foundation()` ?

Comment: @Romain Braun - I am styling everything using the foundation grid. I do not have a 100% grasp on this initialization of foundation for js?

Comment: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html You simply call `$(document).foundation();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take your code out of the `foundation()` call. Also try to remember using semicolons.

```
        $(document).foundation();

        var count = 1;
        $("button.test").click(function(){
            if ($("p.change-me").text() === "OFF") {
                $("p.change-me").text("ON");
                count = count + 1;
            }
            else if ($("p.change-me").text() === "ON") {
                $("p.change-me").text("OFF");
                count = count + 1;
            }
            $("p.counter").text(count);
        })
```

Comment: So you are suggesting that I simply add the $(document).foundation(); and write the rest of my code not within the parenthesis?

Comment: No I'm suggesting that you take your code out of it. It has nothing to do inside the call to foundation.

Comment: Ah okay, this makes sense. Would you recomment that I be so bold as to put it inside of  $(document).ready( function() { });?

Comment: Definitely a good idea, otherwise your jquery function might fail, if the DOM is not ready yet.

Answer (score 0):

@Romain's answer is correct, but just to add to that... `foundation` is a method-call, and you were trying to put javascript code in the section where you normally put parameters (ie inside the `()`). javascript code normally has to go inside of a function's body, not in the section where you type the parameters.

Comment: you are right. I was confused when my original code worked without using the counter.. I am new to front end work and newer to foundation, so I was just plugging away. Thank you and everyone else.